# Is content taken from the outside like video, audio and images etc. considered "Embedded Content" in HTML?

Tags: html, terminology, w3c

I have been reading about *Content Categories* from [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories). In the [Flow Content section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) it says:

> Elements belonging to the flow content category typically contain text or **embedded content**.

But MDN nowhere defines what Embedded content is. As far as I could speculate I think embedded content is somethng that doesn't inherity belongs to the current web page an is actually taken from outside. For example an image, video or iframe -- these represent that is inherent to the webpage like a simple text is. These elements are kind of taken from the outside and embedded onto the page. So,

Is content taken from the outside like video, audio and images etc. considered as "Embedded Content" in HTML?

Comment: You can see it in each element's article, under the "Usage context" paragraph : e.g for [video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#wiki-content) ( same for audio) . "Content categories  Flow content, phrasing content, **embedded content**. If it has a controls attribute: interactive content and palpable content."

Answer (score 0):

Embedded content is content that is sourced from another location on the web. Videos and audio are examples of these.

A great article to enhance your knowledge can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies which briefly discusses embedded content.